# Why is the invoice page different for another user?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

When I go to `admin/store/orders/50457/invoice` as the administrator, I see the following:
[image]

Notice how it has a payment method of "Free order" and the total at the bottom is $0.00.

When I go to the same page as a non-administrator, I see the following:
[image]
Notice how Payment Method is empty and the total for the order is $8.21.

The correct one is what the administrator sees, so what is going on that makes the two behave differently?

EDIT: It turns out in a module I created (a long time ago) called tf_store_credit.module, I have the following:

```
function tf_store_credit_line_item(){

    global $user;
    $total_credit= uc_store_credit_f_get_user_credit($user->uid);

    if ($total_credit>0){
        $items[] = array
          (
            'id' => 'store-credit', // You will use this ID in the javascript 
            'title' => t('Store Credit'), // This is the text that will be displayed on the line item in the subtotal
            'callback' => 'tf_store_credit_line_item_callback', // This is the callback function
            'stored' => TRUE,
            'default' => FALSE,
            'calculated' => TRUE,
            'display_only' => FALSE,
            'weight' => 15,
          );
    }
    return $items;
}
```

The problem is that it is getting the currently logged in user's store credit instead of the user who placed the order. So how would I go about getting the correct user?

Answer (score 0):

In `tf_store_credit.module`, I modified it like this:

```
function tf_store_credit_line_item(){

    global $user;
    $total_credit= uc_store_credit_f_get_user_credit($user->uid);

    if ($total_credit>0 || in_array("view_orders", $user->roles)){
        $items[] = array
          (
            'id' => 'store-credit', // You will use this ID in the javascript 
            'title' => t('Store Credit'), // This is the text that will be displayed on the line item in the subtotal
            'callback' => 'tf_store_credit_line_item_callback', // This is the callback function
            'stored' => TRUE,
            'default' => FALSE,
            'calculated' => TRUE,
            'display_only' => FALSE,
            'weight' => 15,
          );
    }
    return $items;
}
```

In uc_free_order.module, I did a similar thing so that "Payment method" showed up:

```
function uc_free_order_payment_method() {
  global $user;

  if ($user->name=='blah' || $user->name=='blah2' || in_array("view_orders", $user->roles)){
      $methods[] = array(
        'id' => 'free_order',
        'name' => t('Free order'),
        'title' => t('Free order - payment not necessary.'),
        'desc' => t('Allow customers with $0 order totals to checkout without paying.'),
        'callback' => 'uc_payment_method_free_order',
        'checkout' => TRUE,
        'no_gateway' => TRUE,
        'weight' => 10,
      );

      return $methods;
  }
}
```